# modern c++ mechanism for getting thrown exception details

Tags: c++, exception

starting a new c++ project and I am using it as a way of learning to be as modern as possible.

in my prior c++ large projects very early on we established a standard macro that would log and annotate any thrown exception. The annotation included the file name and line number of the throw.

I just wonder if c++ has improved on the whole MACROs, **LINE**, **FILE** mess in the last 20 years. (Same question for logging too)

Any other advice around exceptions would be very welcome (I already have seen, "throw by value, catch by ref", and "derive from std::exception")

Comment: If you have C++ 20, try [source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)

Comment: and since c++11 [std::nested_exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception) may help

Comment: Also `std::exception_ptr` is really useful to save exception (to report them in another thread for example) or simply to make it easier to reuse some exception handling code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - no 20 but thanks thats really what I need. Amazing that it has taken c++ this long to get there